# How do I consume third-party native code from my own native code in Android?

Tags: android, cmake, freetype

I have some native C code that is running in Android via JNI. Actually, the code also runs on iOS. I now want to consume a third-party library ([FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/)) from my native code and I'm having a hard time understanding the best way to achieve this (I haven't done a lot of native development).

My code currently builds on Android via a `CMakeLists.txt` file, which looks something like this:

```
# See https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake.html

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(
    src/main/c/
    ../c/shared/)

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SharedCHeader ../c/shared/*.h)
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SharedCSource ../c/shared/*.c)

add_library(
    native-lib
    SHARED
    ${SharedCHeader}
    ${SharedCSource}
    src/main/c/gl_wrapper.h
    src/main/c/jni.c )

target_link_libraries(
    native-lib
    EGL
    GLESv3)
```

I've managed to compile FreeType for the various ABIs via [this repo](https://github.com/cdave1/freetype2-android), which results in a `.a` file for each architecture. However, I'm not sure how to link those files in so that my other native code can utilize FreeType. I also read somewhere that static and shared libraries can't be mixed, and per the above `CMakeLists.txt`, I am building a `SHARED` library (and I'm not sure if I *need* to).

I also thought to just copy the FreeType code into my own shared code and bundle it into my own `native-lib` library. Indeed, that's why I'm using `GLOB_RECURSE` above, so that it picks up all the FreeType code. This has has resulted in an absolute ton of compilation errors, which I believe would be caused by incorrect configuration/lack of preprocessor definitions. Here's an example:

```
C:/Users/Me/Repository/project/c/shared/freetype_src/type1/type1.c
  In file included from C:/Users/Me/Repository/project/c/shared/freetype_src/type1/type1.c:22:
  In file included from C:/Users/Me/Repository/project/c/shared/freetype_src/type1/t1afm.c:20:
  In file included from C:/Users/Me/Repository/project/c/shared/freetype_src/type1/t1afm.h:23:
  C:/Users/Me/Repository/project/c/shared/freetype_src/type1/t1objs.h:24:10: error: expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
  #include FT_INTERNAL_OBJECTS_H
           ^
```

It seems like preprocessor definitions aren't being applied properly, such that `FT_INTERNAL_OBJECTS_H` is empty when it shouldn't be. I'm not sure how to validate that theory.

Could someone please provide me some guidance here? What is the best way for me to incorporate the FreeType code into the C code in my Android app (bearing in mind I will also want to do the same on iOS)? What steps do I actually need to take to pull this off?

### Update 1

I've managed to make *some* progress by ensuring the `FT2_BUILD_LIBRARY` symbol is defined:

```
add_definitions(-DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY)
```

However, something is *still* going wrong when resolving headers. I get this compilation error now (and only this one, though I'm sure there are more hiding):

```
C:/Users/Me/Repository/project/c/shared/freetype_src/autofit/aflatin2.c:24:10: error: expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
  #include FT_ADVANCES_H
           ^
  1 error generated.
```

Comment: If you are okay with shipping pre-built `.a` files, you can just add them to the sources list in your `add_library` call.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [the repo I linked in my question](https://github.com/cdave1/freetype2-android) as a reference. I copied the source from there instead and it must be an older version because it had files that my (latest) copy didn't have. From there I set my `CMakeLists.txt` to compile the same files and now it at least compiles (yet to actually try something significant).